# Algebra of Sets with Union

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi if I have the following,

$\{x\in X|\,x + x = x^2\}\cup \{x\in X|\, 3x = x^2\}$

Not sure how many numbers are able to go into this, thus what's the easiest way to work this out with the Union?

Thanks

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  They'll look nicer, and you'll get a better reaction from people.  Does $X^2$ mean $\{a^2|a\in X\}?$  Does $X+X$ mean $\{a+b|a\in X,b\in X\}?$

Comment: I edited your question. Did you meant it like this? Then we need to know what $X$ is. Is it  the set $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Cornman Good guess!  I thought it was two equations, but your interpretation makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** :

Assuming $$X = \textbf{R} \text{ (or } \textbf{C} \text{)}$$ 
you can try to resolve
$$
x^2 -2x = 0
$$
and
$$
x^2 -3x=0
$$
Your set is the union of the solutions of these equations.